# How do I get the training loss from the callback function of the Trainer in huggingface

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface

This is my code.This code can be run directly.

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorWithPadding
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers.trainer_callback import DefaultFlowCallback, TrainerCallback, TrainerControl, TrainerState
import numpy as np
import evaluate
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import Trainer
from loguru import logger
import json

logger.add("train_log.log")

raw_dataset = load_dataset("glue", "mrpc")
checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=2)

def tokenizer_function(example):
    return tokenizer(example["sentence1"], example["sentence2"], truncation=True)
tokenizer_datasets = raw_dataset.map(tokenizer_function, batched=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer)

metric = evaluate.load("glue", "mrpc")

def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    logist, labels = eval_preds
    predictions = np.argmax(logist, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

training_args = TrainingArguments("test-trainer",
                                  overwrite_output_dir="test-trainer", 
                                  num_train_epochs=2,
                                  evaluation_strategy="epoch",
                                  save_strategy="epoch")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=2)

class CustomCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def on_train_begin(self, args: TrainingArguments, state: TrainerState, control: TrainerControl, **kwargs):
        logger.info(f"params:{vars(args)}")
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, args: TrainingArguments, state: TrainerState, control: TrainerControl, **kwargs):
        # model = kwargs["model"]
        # logger.info(json.dumps(state.log_history[-1], ensure_ascii=False))
        pass
    
    def on_evaluate(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        logger.info(json.dumps(state.log_history[-1], ensure_ascii=False))

trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenizer_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenizer_datasets["validation"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    callbacks=[CustomCallback]
)
train_result = trainer.train()
```

In the on_epoch_end function, state is an empty list. In on_evaluate, it records the loss and accuracy of the evaluation. I want to also record train loss during the training phase. How do I need to modify it?

environment：
macbook2022-air

python 3.9.6
transformers 4.36.2
datasets  2.16.1

I tried removing compute_metrics=compute_metrics, but the loss is still recorded. I checked the official documentation. He only wrote a few callback functions, but I couldn't find a way to record train loss.